# Google App Script - DriveApp - getParents() not working as expected

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api, google-docs-api

```
MyDrive
|_ Client
|_ tpl
   |_ intake.doc
```

I'm trying to get a reference to the MyDrive folder.

```
  var tpl_intakeDoc = DriveApp.getFileById(docIDs.tpl_intake);
  var parent = tpl_intakeDoc.getParents()[0];
  Logger.log(parent.getName());
```

This gives me the following error:

> TypeError: Cannot call method "getName" of undefined. (line 50, file
>   "Code")

Similarly, trying to iterate through the parent folders (Client and tpl) only shows tpl for some reason.

```
  var parents = tpl_intakeDoc.getParents();
  while (parents.hasNext()) {
    var parents = parents.next();
    Logger.log(folder.getName());
  }
```

All that is logged is:

> [19-06-14 04:14:11:764 MDT] tpl

where I would expect to see something like:

> [19-06-14 04:14:11:764 MDT] tpl
>
> [19-06-14 04:14:11:764 MDT] Client

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `MyDrive`, `Client` and `tpl` are folders.
- `intake.doc` is a file.
- You want to retrieve the folders of `Client` and `tpl` under `MyDrive` using the parent folder of `intake.doc`.
- You want to know about the reason that when your 2nd script is run, only `tpl` is retrieved.

If my understanding is correct, how about this answer? In this answer, your 2nd script was modified.

#### Modification points:

- In your 2nd script in your question, I think that an error occurs when the script is run. So please modify as follows.

  ```
  var tpl_intakeDoc = DriveApp.getFileById(docIDs.tpl_intake); // Added
  var parents = tpl_intakeDoc.getParents();
  while (parents.hasNext()) {
    var parent = parents.next(); // Modified
    Logger.log(parent.getName()); // Modified
  }
  ```
- In above script, the parent folder of `intake.doc` is retrieved. So only `tpl` is returned.
- In order to retrieve the folders of `Client` and `tpl`, the parent folder of `tpl` is required to be retrieved. And retrieve the folders under the parent folder of `tpl`.

The flow of this script is as follows.

1. Retrieve the parent folder of `intake.doc`.

   - `tpl` is retrieved.
2. Retrieve the parent folder of `tpl`.

   - `MyDrive` is retrieved.
3. Retrieve the folders under `MyDrive`.

   - `Client` and `tpl` are retrieved.

#### Modified script:

```
var tpl_intakeDoc = DriveApp.getFileById(docIDs.tpl_intake);
var parent = tpl_intakeDoc.getParents(); // tpl
if (parent.hasNext()) {
  var parentOnParent = parent.next().getParents(); // MyDrive
  if (parentOnParent.hasNext()) {
    var MyDrive = parentOnParent.next().getFolders();
    while (MyDrive.hasNext()) {
      var folder = MyDrive.next();
      Logger.log(folder.getName()) // tpl, Client
    }
  }
}
```

#### Note:

- If `MyDrive` is the root folder, and if you want to retrieve the folders of `tpl` and `Client` from the root folder, I think that [Alberto Molina's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56596897/7108653) is useful for this.

#### References:

- [getParents() of Class File](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file#getparents)
- [getParents() of Class Folder](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/folder#getparents)
- [getFolders()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app#getfolders)

If I misunderstood your question and this was not the direction you want, I apologize.

Answer (score 0):

To get a reference to your “MyDrive” folder, the root of your drive, you would use the function

`var rootFolder = DriveApp.getRootFolder();`

which will return a folder object as if you searched a folder by ID. Below is further documentation on the DriveApp class, which will help you with any other doubt.

Documentation URL: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app#getrootfolder